# Как на Aiogram сделать так,чтобы бот отправлял всем пользователям сообщение?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

К примеру,мне надо отправить сообщение "У бота появилась новая функция!Чтобы попробовать,введите команду /viktorina",всем тем,кто пользуется ботом в чате и в личной странице.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1295502/178576

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отправлять через бота уведомления пользователям зная их id?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295502/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%85-id)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам нужно, при первом сообщении пользователя записывать id в список, а при данной команде циклом перебирать все id и отправлять сообщения всем пользователям из списка. Исходя из безопасности, советую использовать для этого базу данных